# When Connecting To Remote Box SSH Fingerprint Changed After Upgrade from 18.04 to 22.04

Tags: ssh, 22.04, php, openssh

I have a PHP script on my local box that connects to a remote box. Nothing on the remote box changed. And when I connect via the command-line, using the `ssh` command in a terminal, there was no change in the fingerprint. However, a PHP script where I have stored the fingerprint to check it for security, generated an error that the fingerprints did not match.

The relevant line of PHP code that retrieves the fingerprint is:

```
$fingerprint=ssh2_fingerprint($session, SSH2_FINGERPRINT_SHA1);
```

This is retrieving a different fingerprint after the upgrade, from what it did before, when I was running PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu 18. I am now running PHP 8.1. The script is generating no errors, warnings, or notices, even when I set the configuration to display everything, and it was not generating any under the old version either.

I can obviously update the fingerprint, but I would like to understand why this fingerprint has changed because it makes no sense to me and I cannot think of any explanation for why it would have changed when the connection from the terminal shows no change.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to OpenSSH changing the default signature algorithm from `ECDSA` to `ED25519` in version 8.5 (released on 2021-03-03).

Here is a quote from [OpenSSH 8.5 release log](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.5):

```
Potentially-incompatible changes
================================

This release includes a number of changes that may affect existing
configurations:

 * ssh(1), sshd(8): this release changes the first-preference signature
   algorithm from ECDSA to ED25519.
```

I think it will be interesting to you:  [What can cause a changed ssh fingerprint?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/174476/297700)

Comment: My upgrade spanned the pre-8.5 to post-8.5 break so this explains why the fingerprint stored in the PHP script was off. Now I am curious though: why was there no issue when connecting via the command line? Perhaps something, somewhere had specified the algorithm (I never set it manually) when ssh was used from a terminal?